# Video tag moves on play

Tags: css, html, html5-video

Just standard code for a responsive video syntax. Is there a problem with the source tag?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PIXELS: Adventure V. The Five Orange Pips</title>
  <style>
   video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero accusantium aliquam unde explicabo molestias molestiae laboriosam mollitia veniam dicta, inventore, aliquid harum ex omnis! Sapiente ut necessitatibus est, esse facere!</p>
  <video  id="player1" width="480" height="270" controls preload="none">
   <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.ogv" type="video/ogg"> </video>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde placeat eligendi magnam nulla, corporis nobis saepe veniam minus. Quae magni adipisci itaque fugiat pariatur tempora non eligendi, similique rem iusto!</p>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

my video tag is pushing down my layout after clicking the play button. What i am missing?I ve tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>    PIXELS: Adventure V. The Five Orange Pips</title>
    <style>
        video{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero accusantium aliquam unde explicabo molestias molestiae laboriosam mollitia veniam dicta, inventore, aliquid harum ex omnis! Sapiente ut necessitatibus est, esse facere!</p>
    <video  id="player1" width="480" height="270" controls preload="none">
        <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.ogv" type="video/ogg"> </video>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde placeat eligendi magnam nulla, corporis nobis saepe veniam minus. Quae magni adipisci itaque fugiat pariatur tempora non eligendi, similique rem iusto!</p>

</body>
```

Comment: try to set the height to 90%, see if that helps

Comment: remove `="none"` on preload. Your video tag does not know how big your video is before you load it, so will put up an incorrect size. See http://jsfiddle.net/2sdot3t2/

Comment: @NicRobertson, now in Chrome and IE 10 not working,only in Firefox with your solution (strange,in fiddle looks ok).

Comment: @LuckyChingi, not working for me

Comment: @Olegalex try `preload="auto"` or `preload="metadata"`

Comment: @NicRobertson, thanks, seems to work on Firefox and Chrome now with "auto", but the problem is in IE 10, on loading (after some second jumps down,maybe because of the slow connection?!)....such a crap

Comment: @Olegalex I think Internet explorer may not support the `preload` attribute

Comment: @NicRobertson , interesting about video preload: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/ . So, stil i don't understand why is not working with metadata. This should get the size of the video(besides other infos) and should load faster then "auto". But maybe the IE doesn't load anything with metadata(in the table IE with metadata is 0 sec)